# Can't delete registry key Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: vb.net, registrykey

I have been trying all day to get this to work and I can't fathom what the problem is. I have put together a small Windows Form application to manually clean up leftovers from an installation that is being uninstalled company wide. It is all done except for the registry cleanup.

All I am simply trying to do is delete a subkey/ subkey tree. I am using the below code to do so in various different locations. Each time I click the button an exception is thrown stating that the **subkey doesn't exist**. I triple checked the locations of the subkeys and can't make any sense of it. I looks like I have permission to the key, as I am logged in as an administrator, and Administrators group has **full access** to the key; but it throws an **ArgumentException** no matter what:

```
Private Sub btnRegDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegDelete.Click
        My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey("Software\test")
    End Sub
```

It should be that simple shouldn't it? I have also tried using a boolean:

```
Private Sub btnRegDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegDelete.Click
        My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey("Software\test", true)
    End Sub
```

as well as opening the parent key:

```
Public Sub fnDelete()
        Dim oRegKey As RegistryKey

    oRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", True)
    oRegKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("test")
    oRegKey.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRegDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegDelete.Click
     fnDelete()
    End Sub
```

This works fine within the Current_User hive but not under LocalMachine.

Any suggestions would be great. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid, and this should be so simple, just not sure what.

Comment: Did you "Run As" Administrator? (logged in as an admin doesn't mean much on Windows anymore). What version of Windows?

Comment: Hey Ty, thanks for picking this up. same thing if I run the application directly as asministrator. With a try...Catch statement, still throws "cannot delete a subkey tree because the subkey does not exist" for the ex message. Is there a specific set of code you would recommend using for editing the LocalMachine Hive?

Comment: So I think I may have figured it out, but am unsure as to how to go about fixing it. I am running a x64bit Windows 7 Pro OS. It seems the application is running as x86, and is looking by default, in the "SOFTWARE\wow6432Node" key even though I tell it to look in "SOFTWARE" it is really looking in "SOFTWARE\wow6432Node". Unfortuntely I need it to be able to see both. Is there a way do tell the application about x64 but still keep it x86 compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in-case any one strays upon this. The solution was to un-check "**Prefer 32-bit**" processor from the **Project > Properties > Compile** options in *Visual Studio*. "**Target CPU:**" must also be set to "**AnyCPU**" which is not recommended for certain applications.